# PyInstaller error with PySide

Tags: python, pyside, pyinstaller

I have been playing with PyInstaller on Windows 7 (64 bit).  I am currently using PyInstaller 3.1.1 with Python 2.7.6.  I created an app that creates a simple PySide GUI and generated a dist folder with an executable with this command:

```
> C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe .\HelloWidget.spec
```

This is what the spec file looks like:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['HelloWidget.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\spearsc\\Documents\\python_projects\\HelloWorldGui'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[('.\\mainwindow.ui', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='HelloWidget',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='HelloWidget')
```

I wanted to use a spec file, so the .ui file would be bundled along with everything else.  However, when I run the executable, I get this error:

```
> .\HelloWidget.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "c:\users\spearsc\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-djws3k\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line
 389, in load_module
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\__init__.py", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\_utils.py", line 87, in get_pyside_dir
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\_utils.py", line 83, in _get_win32_case_sensitive_name
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\_utils.py", line 58, in _get_win32_short_name
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
pyi_rth_qt4plugins returned -1
```

What is confusing to me is that when I look in the dist folder, I see compiled PySide and Qt files:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\spearsc\Documents\python_projects\HelloWorldGui\dist\HelloWidget


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM      80896 bz2.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   5:20 PM     795278 HelloWidget.exe
-a---         5/24/2016   5:20 PM       1019 HelloWidget.exe.manifest
-a---         5/24/2016   4:42 PM       4102 mainwindow.ui
-a---         5/24/2016   5:20 PM       1052 Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     245760 msvcm90.dll
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     853328 msvcp90.dll
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     641360 msvcr90.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM     248320 pyside-python2.7.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    3063808 PySide.QtCore.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM   12750848 PySide.QtGui.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    1095168 PySide.QtNetwork.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    1052672 PySide.QtUiTools.pyd
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM    3004928 python27.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    3469824 QtCore4.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM   11679744 QtGui4.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    1473536 QtNetwork4.dll
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM      10752 select.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM     330752 shiboken-python2.7.dll
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     689664 unicodedata.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM     111616 _ctypes.pyd
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     474624 _hashlib.pyd
```

Any thoughts?  Can I not trust what I see in the dist folder?

5/25/16:

Well, this is interesting.  I put a print statement in the _get_win32_short_name function.

```
def _get_win32_short_name(s):
    """ Returns short name """
    print s
    buf_size = MAX_PATH
    for i in range(2):
        buf = create_unicode_buffer(u('\0') * (buf_size + 1))
        r = GetShortPathNameW(u(s), buf, buf_size)
        if r == 0:
            raise WinError()
        if r < buf_size:
            if PY_2:
                return buf.value.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
            return buf.value
        buf_size = r
    raise WinError()
```

Here is the result I got back after I built a new executable.

```
> .\HelloWidget.exe
C:\Users\spearsc\DOCUME~1\PYTHON~1\HELLOW~1\dist\HELLOW~1\PySide
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "c:\users\spearsc\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-djws3k\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line
 389, in load_module
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\__init__.py", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\_utils.py", line 88, in get_pyside_dir
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\_utils.py", line 84, in _get_win32_case_sensitive_name
  File "PySide-1.2.2\PySide\_utils.py", line 59, in _get_win32_short_name
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
pyi_rth_qt4plugins returned -1
```

The directory does not exist.  Any ideas on how to get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to add an empty PySide folder in the dist folder.

```
    Directory: C:\Users\spearsc\Documents\python_projects\HelloWorldGui\dist\HelloWidget


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         5/25/2016   2:46 PM            PySide
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM      80896 bz2.pyd
-a---         5/25/2016   2:46 PM     795278 HelloWidget.exe
-a---         5/25/2016   2:46 PM       1019 HelloWidget.exe.manifest
-a---         5/24/2016   4:42 PM       4102 mainwindow.ui
-a---         5/25/2016   2:46 PM       1052 Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     245760 msvcm90.dll
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     853328 msvcp90.dll
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     641360 msvcr90.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM     248320 pyside-python2.7.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    3063808 PySide.QtCore.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM   12750848 PySide.QtGui.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    1095168 PySide.QtNetwork.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    1052672 PySide.QtUiTools.pyd
-a---         5/25/2016   2:46 PM     542208 PySide.QtXml.pyd
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM    3004928 python27.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    3469824 QtCore4.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM   11679744 QtGui4.dll
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM    1473536 QtNetwork4.dll
-a---         5/25/2016   2:46 PM     506368 QtXml4.dll
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM      10752 select.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM     330752 shiboken-python2.7.dll
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     689664 unicodedata.pyd
-a---         5/24/2016   4:43 PM     111616 _ctypes.pyd
-a---         5/23/2016   4:45 PM     474624 _hashlib.pyd
```

After I did that I ran the executable and got an import error for PySide.QtXml, so I generated a new spec file and modified it.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['HelloWidget.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\spearsc\\Documents\\python_projects\\HelloWorldGui'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[('.\mainwindow.ui', '.')],
             hiddenimports=['PySide.QtXml'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='HelloWidget',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='HelloWidget')
```

I then used the spec file to create the executable again.  I added the empty PySide to the dist folder, and it worked!

Comment: I think the source of this issue is that PySide was not in site-packages.  It was located in a different location.